# Bordered Hessian matrix to find a minimum of the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, hessian-matrix

I was trying to find the global minimum for the function $$(a + b) z + (a + c) y + (b + c) x $$ subject to the following constraint: $$(xy + xz + yz)(ab + bc + ac)=1.$$ By Lagrange multipliers I found $2$ as a critical value, but calculating the [bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hessian_matrix&oldid=884558271#Bordered_Hessian) I did not find the answer. Could anyone there help me, please?

Comment: For real variables the minimum does not exist. For non-negative variables the minimum is $0$ of course.  For $(xy+xz+yz)(ab+ac+bc)=1$ and  non-negative variables the answer is $2$,  There is a nice solution.

Comment: can you show me how do you get the minimum for (xy+xz+yz)(ab+bc+ac)?

Comment: Change the problem and I'll show a proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg done!!

Comment: Add that the variables are non-negatives, otherwise the minimum does not exist again.

Comment: do you have three (x,y,z) or six variable function? if six, then you should get 7x7 bordered Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real variables the minimum does not exist.

For non-negative variables by C-S twice we obtain: $$(a+b)z+(a+c)y+(b+c)x=(x+y+z)(a+b+c)-(ax+by+cz)=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz))(a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc))}-(ax+by+cz)\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}+2\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)(ab+ac+bc)}-(ax+by+cz)\geq$$
$$\geq ax+by+cz+2\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)(ab+ac+bc)}-(ax+by+cz)=2.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt3},$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: it's suficient a=x,b=y and c=z to  occur equality

Comment: please send your email for me

Comment: @Israel Meireles Chrisostomo If you want to say me something so you can make it in the forum AoPS: My nick there it's arqady Send me your message. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/